# How can this line of code acccess into this method?

Tags: java, class, methods, awt

I'm a beginner using Java, and I would like to learn more about the language.
Of course I saw a complete list of videos to learn more about the language and I know even how to create windows with the language.
But there's one line that I don't understand pretty well, this is the line.

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

As I can understand, we are creating an object called screenSize with Dimension, which this uses the Toolkit object to get the screen size.

But something that I don't understand is how can the Toolkit class access into the getScreenSize(); method if the class is using getDefaultToolkit() ? I think it's because Toolkit extends from some other class, but I'm not sure.

I would like if someone can explain to me how this works.
Thank you for the possible replies.
Regards.

Comment: Actually, you are creating a variable named screenSize of type Dimention which is being assigned the value being returned by the getScreenSize() method, which is being run on the object returned by getDefaultToolkit(), which is a static method on the Toolkit class.

Comment: Basically, `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` gives you an Object (a Toolkit apparently). So from that object, you can then call `getScreenSize()`. You'll often see that kind of method chain in Java.

Comment: You're chaining method calls.  `getDefaultToolkit` is a `static method of the `Toolkit` class, meaning you don't need an instance of `Toolkit` to call it.  `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` returns the "default" instance of the `Toolkit` been used by the system.  `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` would be the same as doing `Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();` followed by `toolkit.getScreenSize();`